# Serving Flask + React App with Gunicorn on Heroku Code H10 Path "/" and "/favicon.ico"

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, gunicorn

I tried to serve a vanilla React app (created with create-react-app and no further modification - just created the react app and built it as it is) with a Flask api using Gunicorn, but it fails on Heroku with code H10. I couldn't pinpoint why the application is failing. It is working fine locally. Not sure if this can be the cause, I have used virtual environment (venv) locally. Any ideas why it's failing? Thanks!

The error in the Heroku logs below.

```
2020-06-13T03:20:19.425468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testdeployd.herokuapp.com request_id=302fe53f-2346-4c31-bf69-a6411da8a7b1 fwd="173.68.90.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-13T03:20:19.806856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testdeployd.herokuapp.com request_id=ea82a928-dcab-4931-a60b-8d63f4417c0a fwd="173.68.90.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-13T03:20:20.166173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testdeployd.herokuapp.com request_id=3c673c5f-ad5f-466d-92b0-830cdaff4f48 fwd="173.68.90.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The directory structure is below.

```
myapp
 |->api
     |->api.py
     |->.flasenv
     |->venv
 |->build
 |->node_modules
 |->public
 |->src
 ...
 |->Procfile
 |->requirements.txt
```

The content of api.py is below.

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder="../build", static_url_path="/")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

I put the following in my Procfile.

```
web: gunicorn -b :5000 --pythonpath api api:app
```

Added the following the `package.json` file.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

directory structure:

```
├── api
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── build
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── precache-manifest.8561e2012c98e084450b035cf3321061.js
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       ├── js
│       └── media
├── gunicorn.conf.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── static
└── templates
```

```py
#app.py

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../build', static_url_path="/")


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```py
#gunicorn.conf.py
# thanks https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker/blob/master/python3.7/Dockerfile

import json
import multiprocessing
import os

workers_per_core_str = os.getenv("WORKERS_PER_CORE", "2")
web_concurrency_str = os.getenv("WEB_CONCURRENCY", None)
if os.getenv('FLASK_ENV', 'development') == 'production':
    host = os.getenv("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
    port = os.getenv("PORT", "8000")
else:
    host = os.getenv("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
    #  on a unix-like environment, ports < 1024 (like 80) will require superuser privileges.
    # port need as same as config.config.py SERVER_NAME port
    port = os.getenv("PORT", "5000")
bind_env = os.getenv("BIND", None)
use_loglevel = os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "info")
if bind_env:
    use_bind = bind_env
else:
    use_bind = f"{host}:{port}"

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
workers_per_core = float(workers_per_core_str)
default_web_concurrency = workers_per_core * cores
if web_concurrency_str:
    web_concurrency = int(web_concurrency_str)
    assert web_concurrency > 0
else:
    web_concurrency = int(default_web_concurrency)

# Gunicorn config variables
loglevel = use_loglevel
workers = web_concurrency
bind = use_bind
keepalive = 120

# For debugging and testing
log_data = {
    "loglevel": loglevel,
    "workers": workers,
    "bind": bind,
    # Additional, non-gunicorn variab`les
    "workers_per_core": workers_per_core,
    "host": host,
    "port": port,
}
print(json.dumps(log_data))
```

run

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py  api.app:app
```

you can see this in 127.0.0.1:5000
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtMb1.png)

### note

I use create-react-app create project and then use `yarn build`(I didn't change anything)

You can just use `flask run && yarn start` to development, and may be you need `flask-cors` [flask-cors](https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors)  to allow flask cors in dev

Comment: Thanks! I can run the whole thing without any problem locally, but it doesn't work on heroku. Always throwing the same error shown above.

Comment: Did you get how to deploy? I'm still stuck on deploying.